# Offsetting a 3D object in the camera's view

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, xna-4.0

I'm new here. I'm having a bit of trouble on the last bit of rendering my model in accordance(Is that a word?) to my camera's view angle.

I have succeeded in creating my 3D camera, being able to rotate it in 3D space, and move/rotate my gun model to correspond with the camera's movements/ rotations.

The final part however, I cannot figure out. I'm trying to offset the gun model's position on the camera's rotated axes, but can't find anything about how to do so.

This is the code I have so far, without the offset I would like.

```
GunWorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f) * 
    CameraRotation * 
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(CameraPosition);
```

It ends up placing the gun "in my head", so to speak. perfectly positions and rotates the model, but I don't know how to add any offset based on either it's own axes or the camera's. (So you can have it in a hip fire position, etc.)

Although, This;

```
Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 2, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);
```

as the view, with this;

```
GunWorldMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f) *
    Matrix.CreateRotationX(-0.15f) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0.2f, 1.65f, 0f));
```

as the Guns World Matrix was perfectly positioned if it were frozen to axes with no rotation... which may or may not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a guy over on another forum, he came up with this;

```
float verticalOffset = 1.65f;  
float longitudinalOffset = 0f;  
float lateralOffset = .2f;  

GunWorldMatrix = Matrix.Invert(view); // GunWorldMatrix is now a world space version of the camera's Matrix with position & orientation of the camera  
Vector3 camPosition = GunWorldMatrix.Translation;// note position of camera so when setting gun position, we have a starting point.  

GunWorldMatrix *= Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(GunWorldMatrix.Up, 0.15f); // gives the gun that slight angle to point towards target while laterally offset a bit  

Vector3 gunPositionOffsets = (GunWorldMatrix.Up * verticalOffset) +  
                                (GunWorldMatrix.Forward * longitudinalOffset) +  
                                (GunWorldMatrix.Right * lateralOffset);  

GunWorldMatrix.Translation = camPosition + gunPositionOffsets;
```

Which gives me my answer. Thanks for your answer though, Aki. It led me down the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The viewMatrix (modeling the camera), consists of three orthogonal vectors:
X=[xx,xy,xz], Y=[yx,yy,yz], Z=[zx,zy,zz]  plus cameras position T=[tx,ty,tz]

```
[xx yx zx   tx]   --> order is [0 4      ]             [ 0 1  2 ]
[xy yy zy   ty]                [1 5      ]  -> R^-1 =  [ 4 5  6 ]
[xz yz zz   tz]                [2 ...    ]             [ 8 9 10 ]
[0  0  0     1]                [3      15]
```

Here typically Y vector represents *Up*, X is *right* and Z is where to *lookAt* -- all are normalized to length 1.

You need to be concerned only about the upper left 3x3 Rotation matrix and it's inverse R^-1, which for normalized rotation matrices are trivially the transpose: R^-1 = R'.

To move something at "screen" right, you'll add to object.t_vector += camera^(-1).x_vector. This can be also scaled by distance, FoV and aspect ratio to move an object exactly 1 pixel right or proportionally to the screen dimensions.

Note: This is openGL convention of view matrix, where the vectors are *column vectors* and the matrices are in column-row order. Other systems may represent or store the matrices in row-column order.

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but I tried altering the values manually, and boy, did it produce some interesting effects. I now see how some models in video games get so screwed up sometimes. Is it possible for you to show an example on how it could be done in the model's world matrix? There's gotta be a way to offset it with a simple translation or something.. Or is there a way you could show me how your explanation could work in c#?